# Is there a way to "activate" word-wrapping in SwiftUI?

Tags: swiftui

Is there an alternative to UIKit's LineBreakMode in SwiftUI?
Or are there any alternatives to get the Text truncated via words not via characters in SwiftUI?

I've tried the

```
 .fixedSize(horizontal: false, vertical: true)
```

approach but it does not seem to work.

Update with the code:

```
VStack {
     HStack {
        CustomText("Some Text")
        Spacer()
        SomeOtherView()
     }.padding(.horizontal, 16)
}
```

Update:

```
struct CustomText: View {
    
    // MARK: - Properties
    
    let text: String
    let color: Color?
    
    // MARK: - Init
    
    init(text: String, color: Color? = Colors.darkGrey) {
        self.text = text
        self.color = color
    }
    
    // MARK: - Body
    
    var body: some View {
        Text(text)
            .tracking(0.256)
            .fontWithLineHeight(font: Fonts.header2, lineHeight: 33)
            .foregroundColor(color)
            .minimumScaleFactor(0.5)
            .lineLimit(nil)
        
    }
}
```

Some other view is just a Lottie Animation View so it should not make any difference.
An observation is that SwiftUI prefers to add hyphenation rather than minimising the font => I think that the priority of hyphenation is bigger than the minimumScaleProperty.

Comment: Actually word-wrapping is activated by default. Could you provide minimal reproducible example of code which do not work for you?

Comment: That is actually not a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) that @Asperi asked for. We don't know what a`CustomText()` is, nor do we know what `SomeOtherView()` is. I would suspect that you didn't set a `lineLimit()` properly somewhere.

Comment: I just made an update.